# Photos streamed to Samsung TV are too small

Tags: windows, windows-10, tv, photos

I would like to stream my photos from Win10 PC to Samsung TV using Right-click on photo, Play to -> Samsung TV.

Generally it works fine, but the photos are like thumbnails on the TV.

I was looking to Media streaming options, but there are no options regarding size of the photos.

Any tips where should I look?

Comment: Is it all photos or just some?  What's the resolution of the photos?  What's the resolution of the TV?

Comment: The TV is Samsung ue55h6872- 3840 x 2160. All photos one of the example is 4608x3456. Strange is that if I do the same to my older Sony HD TV the photo is fullscreen.